# ASP.NET Core WebAPI 2 PUT method name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I have been struggling for a while and cannot seem to get this to work.

I have a Controller, say "Teacher".

I want a PUT action with a different name, but accepts `[FromBody]` a complex DTO.

How can I invoke it? Everything I tried is giving me a 404.

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Teacher")]
public class TeacherController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITeacherService _teacherService;

    public TeacherController(ITeacherService teacherService)
    {
        this._teacherService = teacherService;
    }

    [HttpPut("UpdateTeacherForInterview")]
    public IActionResult PutTeacherForInterview(int id, [FromBody]UpdateInterviewModel model)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

I have tried (and cried!):

```
PUT /api/Teacher/1 (and complex object)

PUT /api/Teacher/UpdateTeacherForInterview/1 (and complex object)

PUT /api/Teacher/PutTeacherForInterview/1 (and complex object)
```

I always get a 404.

The simple Put works i.e:

```
[HttpPut]
public IActionResult Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

But I want to use a different action name.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The route template was not matching the URL being called

```
//Matches PUT api/Teacher/UpdateTeacherForInterview/1
[HttpPut("UpdateTeacherForInterview/{id:int}")]
public IActionResult PutTeacherForInterview(int id, [FromBody]UpdateInterviewModel model) {
    return Ok();
}
```

Reference [Routing to Controller Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Comment: @Ahmedilyas I was the same way when I started. Chalk it up to me learning the hard way so that you don't have to. lol